# Proving $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}\cap \ell^2$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In a book of metric space topology  it is claimed that $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}\cap \ell^2$ is uncountable where $\ell^2$ is a space of square-summable real sequences. This means we have to show that the set all rational square-summable sequences is uncountable. I don't know to to start. Kindly help!

Comment: The intersection contains $S:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\,\Biggl(\left[-\frac{1}{n},+\frac{1}{n}\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}\Biggr)$ as a subset.  Show that $S$ and $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ are equicardinal.

Comment: how intersection contains S , since S has uncountably many irrationals

Comment: I meant $\left[-\frac{1}{n},+\frac{1}{n}\right]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ (this should have been trivial to you).  See the edit.

Comment: yes this works well

Comment: For every positive real number $r$, there is a square-summable rational sequence with square sum equal to $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be the set of binary sequences. Recall that $B$ and $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality. The map $B \to \mathbb Q ^{\mathbb N} \cap l^2$ given by

$$(b_n) \to (b_1/1,b_2/2, \dots , b_n/n, \dots )$$

is injective, giving the result.